# Handling a sequence of unevaluated arguments

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

I have the following piece of code:

```
SetAttributes[createPlayers, HoldAll];
createPlayers[names__] :=
  (Clear[player];
   players = 
    Table[numOfPlayers = i; 
     player[i] = {names}[[i]], {i, Length[{names}]}]);

createPlayers["Aron", "Geoff", "Steve"];

gameStats[stats__] :=
  Grid[{
    Table[SymbolName[Unevaluated[{stats}]][[i]], {i, Length@{stats}}],
    Table[{stats}[[i]], {i, Length@{stats}}]
    }, Frame -> All];

gameStats[numOfPlayers, player[1], player[2], player[3]] // Dynamic
```

This does three tasks:

1. A function to create as many players as required. These players' names can then be viewed with `player[i]`. The total number of players is also stored in the variable `numOfPlayers`.
2. It creates three players by the names Aron, Geoff and Steve respectively.
3. `gameStats` creates a grid displaying useful stats about the game.

Functions 1 and 2 work fine. I can't get function 3 to work though. What I am trying to get at is to display a grid with the symbol names in the top row, and their values in the bottom row - like so:

[image]

Instead the best I can do is this:

[image]

Either the top row displays the variables' values - which means that both top and bottom rows are the same - or it displays this error message. How can I get the top row to display the variables' symbol names properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try this:

```
SetAttributes[gameStats, HoldAll];
gameStats[stats__] := Grid[{List @@ HoldForm /@ Hold[stats], {stats}}, Frame -> All];
gameStats[numOfPlayers, player[1], player[2], player[3]]
```

[image: grid]

#### Update

You might also want to try this as well. It simplifies your code for `createPlayers`. First remove the line

```
SetAttributes[createPlayers, HoldAll];
```

from your code. You don't need that; you are only passing strings, which are atomic to the kernel. They can not be evaluated into anything else. Then evaluate the following definition.

```
createPlayers[args__String] :=
  Module[{names = {args}},
    Clear[player];
    players = Length @ names;
    Do[player[i] = names[[i]], {i, players}]]
```

#### Update 2

This is in response to a request for me to "explain what is going on behind the scenes and why this works?". I am assuming that it is the expression `{List @@ HoldForm /@ Hold[stats], {stats}}` that is causing confusion. To explain it, I will introduced a function `f` that deals with this expression alone, thus reducing the issue to its bare bones.

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[args__] := List[Apply[List, Map[HoldForm, Hold[args]]], List[args]]
```

I have written the above code in long form so that all the functions used are clearly visible. I have given `f` the `HoldAll` attribute because it will use `args`, the sequence of one more arguments passed to it, in both unevaluated and evaluated form.

Now let's use `Trace` to see what happens when `f` is evaluated with the argument sequence `a, b, c`, where a = 1`,`b = 2`,`c = 3`.

```
{a, b, c} = Range@3;
Trace[f[a, b, c]]
```

> ```
> (* 1 *)  {f[a, b, c],
> (* 2 *)  {{List @@ HoldForm /@ Hold[a, b, c], {a, b, c}},
> (* 3 *)  {{{HoldForm /@ Hold[a, b, c], Hold[a, b, c]},
> (* 4 *)   {List @@ Hold[a, b, c], {a, b, c}},
> (* 5 *)  {{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {1, 2, 3}},
> (* 6 *)  {{{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}}}
> ```

Here is step-by-step explanation of what `Trace` is telling us.

1. The function call.
2. The unevaluated argument sequences substituted in the expression in two places
3. `HoldForm` is mapped over the arguments `a`, `b`, and `c`, giving `Hold[HoldForm[a], HoldForm[a], HoldForm[a]]`. We don't see `HoldForm` anymore because *Mathematica*'s output printer makes it invisible. Recall that acting like `Hold` but being invisible on print-out is the whole purpose of `HoldForm`.
4. `Apply` replaces `Hold` with `List` returning a list of variable names still wrapped in `HoldForm`.
5. The 2nd element in the list `(* 2 *)` is now evaluated; each variable is evaluated here because they are naked -- no holding form protects them.
6. The output expression (wrapped in a list by `Trace`}.

Comment: Hi @m_goldberg, thanks so much for this! I understand what you've done with the `createPlayers` function. However although the `gameStats` function also works perfectly, could you quickly explain what is going on behind the scenes and why this works?

Comment: For what it's worth: `HoldForm /@ Unevaluated @ {stats}` might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
Grid[{Join[{HoldForm[numOfPlayers]}, 
   Table[With[{x = x}, HoldForm[player[x]]], {x, 1, numOfPlayers}]],
  Join[{numOfPlayers}, Table[player[x], {x, 1, numOfPlayers}]]}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Note that `player` is a symbol, *not* `player[n]`.